# Logging into a server with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to write parser. And I must login there:
http://24travels.pl/web/export.pl?o=10004&co=imprezy

But this is not POST form. This is a .htaccess server lock.
Anyone have idea to login there Using a curl or something?

I need to do auto parser from this site, but first I must login there.

Comment: .htaccess lock? aka HTTP basic authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` to achieve this.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://24travels.pl/web/export.pl?o=10004&co=imprezy');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[username]:[password]')

$data = curl_exec();
curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```